# Proximity between two Microsoft Band

Tags: wifi, physics, microsoft-band

We are working on an application that can find proximate distance between two Microsoft Band.
We explored options like Bluetooth but we could not find this as a better solution for our problem due to lot of limitation of Bluetooth.
Currently API's for accessing band GPS data are not available.
So is there any way we can find proximate distance between two Microsoft bands?

Comment: What precision do you mean by "proximate"?  Are both Bands connected with the same phone/PC, or separate phones/PCs?

Comment: Both bands are connected to the same phone. Proximate means both the bands are not within a specific range to each other. range would be around 5 to 10 meters.

Comment: If you use a known starting point for the Bands (e.g. the phone, using its GPS sensor), then you may be able to use "dead reckoning" techniques to approximate their relative location, using the Bands accelerometer and/or gyroscope sensors.  I have no idea, however, whether or not those sensors and their reporting interval are sufficient to calculate a meaningful position.  I'm not sure that the Band's GPS sensors would give significantly better information given the ranges you describe and given the typical error margins for GPS sensors.  (Not that I know the Band GPS sensor details.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for finding distance between bands. The GPS sensors are not available to 3rd party developers. In the case of trying to find the distance between two bands you would need to run code on another device (mobile phone) to calculate the distance and as such using two mobile devices, each paired with a band, would be the way to handle this.

If you have a feature request for a future version of the band you can submit it at: https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com